# What's the quickest way to generate script tags for the dependencies in a google-closure project?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, google-closure

I'm learning JavaScript and Google Closure, and obviously (once you start using templates and various parts of the library) it becomes difficult to manage the dependencies by hand.

I know that the library provides some python scripts to help with this but I can't quite figure out the best way to use them.

(I know that eventually I'll be compiling it all into a single 'minimized' file but for development and my own understanding I feel I need to get my head round this bit first!)

The closest I've got is to use the "closurebuilder.py" script to produce a list of files in dependency order...

```
closure-library/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py 
    --root=MyProjectFolder
    --root=ClosureLibraryFolder
    --root=ClosureTemplateFolder
    --namespace=MyProjectNamespace
    --output_mode=list
    --output_file=my-dependencies.txt
```

...but I then still need to manually wrap each one in a script tag and paste them into my html.  Am I missing something?  Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just getting started, you might find Michael Bolin's Plovr (http://www.plovr.com/) useful so you don't need to futz with your setup.

Comment: Ah yeah...and according to the documentation, I should be able to use it in "RAW" mode to produce the <script> tags for the dependencies when required, as well as a convenient way of compiling the minimized file. Thanks...I'll have a go.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you should use calcdeps.py

http://code.google.com/closure/library/docs/calcdeps.html

Comment: Thanks...I thought I read somewhere that calcdeps was deprecated. I'm not sure what the replacement is meant to be, but plovr is working pretty well for me for now.

Comment: FYI, calcdeps was replaced by the ClosureBuilder.. you can see that here: http://code.google.com/closure/library/docs/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single javascript file to include, then use:

```
--output_mode=script
```

or

```
--output_mode=compiled
```